# Real Time Loader Percentage Springboot and Angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I have application angular and spring boot. In that i need to show percentage of loader real time from springboot to angular.

Ex. I have 5000 record which needs to load from database and need to display on angular via springboot application what is easiest way to do. In that also i need to make sure it per browser tab. it means if user open next and load data that loader percentage should not mix with firsttab.

I have created one api in springboot which gives me result real time. It means i updating flag while iterating data and putting in DTO object. But i am not able to bifurcate between two tab or two session. Can you help on that.